# Kendo Dropdown sync not working inside Kendo Menu

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to use kendo dropdown inside a Kendo Menu. The dropdown is rendering fine. I have added noDatatemplate inside kendo dropdown to add new item to my datasource. But when i click on Add button, the newly added item is not showing inside the dropdown. When i try to console the dropdown datasource, i see the newly added item there. So, datasource.sync() is not rendering the newly added value in the dropdown.
If i use it this outside the kendo menu then it is working fine.
Please suggest what i can do to make it work.

Kendo Menu Html

```js
var arr=[{destination:"ABC",destination:"XYZ"}];
$(window).on('load', function () {  
    
    $("#mainSapMenu").kendoMenu({       
        
       
    });});
function AddMenuClick() {        
    BindDestination();   
}
function BindDestination(){
$("#drpSapDest").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "destination",
        dataValueField: "destination",       
        optionLabel: "--Select--",
        filter: "startswith",
        dataSource:arr,
        noDataTemplate:$("#nodestinationTemplate").html(),
        valuePrimitive: true,        
    });
}
function addNewItem(id, val) {    
    var widget = $("#" + id).getKendoDropDownList();
    var datasource = widget.dataSource; 
    if (id == "drpSapDest") {
        datasource.add({ "destination": val });        
    }``           
    datasource.one("sync", function () {
        widget.select(dataSource.view().length - 1);
    });
    datasource.sync(); 
    
    
}
```

```html
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="mainSapMenu">
            <li id="addNewMenuClick" onclick="AddMenuClick();">
                Add
                <ul> 
                    <li>
                        <div id="searchTemplate" style="padding: 10px;">
                            <div class="row">
                               <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3">Destination</label>:
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                        <input id="drpSapDest" class="selectpicker" />
                                        <script id="nodestinationTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
                                            <div>
                                                No data found. Do you want to add , click below - '#: instance.filterInput.val() #' ?
                                            </div>
                                            <br />
                                            <button  class="k-button" style="background-color:\\#00547d;color:\\#fff"  onclick="addNewItem('#: instance.element[0].id #', '#: instance.filterInput.val() #')">Add</button>
                                        </script>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                               
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3"></label>
                                    <button class="btn blue-btn-small" onclick="CreateNewNode();"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"> </i> Add</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            
                        </div>
                    </li>
                   

                </ul>
            </li>
           
            <li id="searchMenuClick" onclick="RefreshMenuClick();">
                Refresh
            </li>           
        </ul>
```

Comment: Could you add the code you are using? Try to share a minimum reproducible example of what and how you are using this.

Comment: @germanio, please check